# Taking 2 command line inputs and verifying that they are integers, within the correct range of values

Tags: performance, c, parsing, converting

I'm taking 2 command line inputs, which have to be integers between 2 and 1,000,000. These two values are then passed into the `getPrimes` function, which is just a Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm, printing all prime numbers within the range specified by the two inputs. The two inputs, `n` and `k`, must be positive integers, where `n` > `k`. How can I better optimise my approach to collecting these inputs and verifying them, to decrease execution time?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXVALUE 1000000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    if (argc != 3){
        printf("Warning: Check number of arguments.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int i, j;
    for (j = 1; j <= 2; j++){
        for (i = 0; argv[j][i] != '\0'; i++){
            if (!isdigit(argv[j][i])) {
                printf("Warning: Please enter a valid integer.\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    int n = atoi(argv[2]), k = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (n > MAXVALUE || k == 1 || k >= n){
        printf("Warning: Bad input.\n");
        return 1;
    } 

    // getPrimes(n, k);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you *know* there are only going to be two numbers passed, then I would skip the first loop and do two explicit calls to a function that can read a number. Looking at "scanf/vscanf" might help you there.

Comment: @user1777136 I know there will be two arguments, but I don't know if the user will necessarily input two numbers.

Comment: Mhm, but isn't that covered by `if (argc != 3)`. I'm arguing for something like `int n = parse_number_argument(argv[1]); int k = parse_number_argument(argv[2]);` being possibly a little cleaner.

Comment: @user1777136 What I'm saying is that the user may input `dauw wo^%Dh`, which isn't covered by `if (argc != 3)`

Comment: I think it is, your shell (or something up the stack?) will already split arguments based on spaces? http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function#tss_delete

Comment: @user1777136 What he means is he needs to verify that the argument is an integer before checking if it's in the appropriate range.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987644/validate-input-cmdline-input-argv-contains-all-integers for how to validate that a string is an integer using `strtol()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is unrelated to performance, but it may still be helpful in general:

- [You should print those errors to `stderr` via `fprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

  ```
  fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Check number of arguments.\n");
  ```

  ```
  fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Please enter a valid integer.\n");
  ```

  ```
  fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Bad input.\n");
  ```
- Are you using a pre-C99 version of C?  If not, you should be initializing the loop counter variables within the loop conditions, not outside of them.
- It's common to provide the types of expected arguments (starting with whatever gets printed from `argv[0]`) if this check fails. You could also specify the number of expected arguments so that the user isn't left guessing, in case the objective isn't already clear.

  ```
  fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Check number of arguments (must be 2).\n");
  ```
- You shouldn't try to do everything in `main()`, and it doesn't look like those checks after the arguments check belong there.

  Instead, consider providing separate functions for both that get called from `main()`. They can return a boolean value and, if it's an erroneous one, the program can then terminate from `main()`.
- If I'm not mistaken, the `for` loop is supposed to check both `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` for valid data types.

  If so, you could either:

  1. Do two separate checks without a loop (to maybe make it a little more cleaner)
  2. If you may consider expanding it for additional arguments, use `argc` as part of the outer loop sentinel value instead of hard-coding the `2` (which could be seen as a "magic number" instead anyway)

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem: `atoi()` returns [an undefined value](http://illumos.org/man/atoi) if the input overflows type `int`.  The user might enter a stupidly large number, like 945066360948394517322619797713, and your program might or might not detect that this number is over 1 million.

For a real example, `atoi("4294967396")` returns 100 in my computer running OpenBSD/amd64.  If the user typed 4294967396 as the second input, then your program would show the primes up to 100, as if there were no primes from 101 to 4294967396.

You may use `strtol()` to detect overflow.  If the number is too large, `strtol()` returns LONG_MAX, which is more than 1 million.  A conversion function might look like

```
static int arg2int(const char *arg, int *iv) {
    long lv;
    char *end;

    if (!isdigit((unsigned char)arg[0]))
        return 0;
    lv = strtol(arg, &end, 10);
    if (end[0] != '\0' || lv < 2 || lv > 1000000)
        return 0;
    /* Assume 1000000 fits in an int. */
    *iv = (int)lv;
    return 1;
}
```

Thanks to @chux for reminding me that `isdigit(arg[0])` is undefined behavior when `arg[0] < 0`.  I have edited the code, adding the `(unsigned char)` cast.

To check that `arg` contains only digits, it is enough that `isdigit((unsigned char)arg[0])` and `end[0] != '\0'` are true.  This is because `strtol()` allows whitespace and `'+'` and `'-'` before the number, and any garbage characters after the number.

Comment: Missed corner: If arg[0] has various negative values, isdigit(arg[0]) is UB.

Comment: @chux is correct; [isdigit(3)](http://man.openbsd.org/isdigit) warns, "The argument *c* must be EOF or representable as an unsigned char; otherwise, the result is undefined."

Answer (score 1):

> Taking 2 command line inputs and verifying that they are integers, within the correct range of values
>
> How can I better optimise my approach to collecting these inputs and verifying them, to decrease execution time?

1. The execution time of the front-end code is a very minor consideration as code is to later do the *Sieve of Eratosthenes*.
2. To optimize, call a common function that handles the string to number conversion and check.  `strtol()` is the key.  Make the function flexible for this and other applications.  Further, leading white-spaces and an optional sign (`'-'`, `'+'`) should be tolerated.  As command line arguments, leading/trailing white-spaces are not expected, yet still recommend that a generic conversion routine tolerate them.

I see 5 separate reasons to fail conversion.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// return false is no error, else true.
bool JBS_strtol_ranged(long *dest, const char * nptr, long min, long max) {
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  *dest = strtol(nptr, &endptr, 10);
  if (*dest < min) {
    errno = ERANGE; // Set ERANGE & *dest for consistent functionality
    *dest = min;
    return true; // subrange overflow
  }
  if (*dest > max) {
    errno = ERANGE; // Set ERANGE & *dest for consistent functionality
    *dest = max;
    return true; // subrange overflow
  }
  if (nptr == endptr) {
    return true; // no conversion  *dest = 0
  }
  if (errno) {
    return true; // overflow or implementation specific failure
  }
  // Be generous, allow the string to have trailing white-space
  while (isspace((unsigned char ) *endptr)) {
    endptr++;
  }
  if (*endptr) {
    return true; // extra junk at the end
  }
  return false; // no error
}
```

Example usage.  Note the range change to insure `n > k`

```
#define MINVALUE 2
long n, k;
if (JBS_strtol_ranged(argv[2], &n, MINVALUE, MAXVALUE) || 
    JBS_strtol_ranged(argv[1], &k, MINVALUE, n-1)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Please enter valid integers.\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the following proposed code:

1. the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* is followed
2. appropriate horizontal spacing (for readability) has been added
3. the check for valid values of the command line parameters has been corrected
4. makes use of the function: `exit()` with parameter `EXIT_FAILURE`
5. uses a good error statement, output to `stderr`, when any error is found.
6. minimizes the 'scope' of the local 'index' variables 'i' and 'j'
7. only includes header files those contents are used and documents why each header file is included

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(),
#include <stdlib.h>  // atoi(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
//#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>   // isdigit()

#define MAXVALUE 1000000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s [maxPrime >=2] [MaxPrime<=1000000]\n", argv[0] );
        //printf("Warning: Check number of arguments.\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        //return 1;
    }

    // implied else, correct number of command line arguments

    for ( int j = 1; j < argc; j++ )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; argv[j][i] != '\0'; i++ )
        {
            if ( !isdigit( argv[j][i] ) )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "Warning: Please enter a valid integer.\n");
                //printf("Warning: Please enter a valid integer.\n");
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                //return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    int n = atoi( argv[2] );
    int k = atoi( argv[1] );

    if ( n > MAXVALUE || n < 2 || k < 2 || k > n )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "prime range (2...100000) exceeded\n" );
        //printf("Warning: Bad input.\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        //return 1;
    }

    // implied else, parameter values acceptable

    // getPrimes( n, k );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: suggest using `strtol()` instead of `atoi()` so the code can check that the conversion was successful.

Comment: Off by 1.  To match "n > k" requirement, use `|| k >= n` rather than `>`.

Comment: @chux,  I agree with your observation.